# Iterating over list of lists in Python by comparing every next list with previous one and storing the unique lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, compare, store

I have a list of lists in python with two float values in each list. I would like to iterate on list of lists, but I desire to store first list in resulting list and compare every next list with the previous one and if it is different from the previous list then I again need to store that list in the resulting list.

```py
list_of_lists = [[0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [0.9953129999999999, 13.625421],[0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995],[1.7293490000000002, 1.5182360000000001]]
```

My initial approach is like this;

```
resulting_list = []
resulting_list.insert(0,list_of_list[0])
print (resulting_list)
for index, rows in list_of_lists:
if ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats your expected output of resulting_list to look like?

Comment: I would like to see the output in a 2D-numpy array but output in list or list of lists would also works. For example; at the moment the resulting_list looks like this [[0.9953129999999999, 13.625421]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you put the first sublist in resulting lists. and then iterate over the remaining items, you can then check if the current sublist matches the last sublist in resulting list, if it doesnt then ad this sublist.

```py
list_of_lists = [[0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [0.9953129999999999, 13.625421],
                 [0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.6215, 3.26078],
                 [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871],
                 [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871],
                 [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995],
                 [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995],
                 [1.7293490000000002, 1.5182360000000001]]

resulting_list = [list_of_lists[0]]
for sub_list in list_of_lists[1:]:
    if sub_list != resulting_list[-1]:
        resulting_list.append(sub_list)
print(resulting_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995], [1.7293490000000002, 1.5182360000000001]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a classic "reduce" operation on the list. This way you don't need a for loop:

```
import functools
def reducer(x,y):
    if(len(x)==0 or x[-1]!=y): return(x+[y])
    return(x)
functools.reduce(reducer, list_of_lists, list())
```

You start with an empty list as the initial value for the accumulator and keep adding new elements if they are different from the last one added.

Output:

`[[0.9953129999999999, 13.625421], [1.6215, 3.26078], [1.0, 12.25871], [1.9050619999999998, 0.011995], [1.7293490000000002, 1.5182360000000001]]`

If you want to be even more concise you can pass an anonymous lambda function directly in the call to reduce

```
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+[y] if(len(x)==0 or x[-1]!=y) else x, list_of_lists, list())
```